# F# Lambda Signature

Tags: .net, f#

I'm reading Programming F# by Chris Smith right now trying to figure out F# when i come across Lambadas. Here is a lambda from one of the examples

```
let generatePowerOfFunc base = (fun exponent -> base ** exponent);;
```

I get that it takes in something and returns a function, but what i don't get is the Signature of this function which is `val generatePowerOfFunc : float -> float -> float`

How does it have three floats instead of two? And when there's this method

`let powerOfTwo = generatePowerOfFunc 2.0;;`

It only has 2 floats `val powerOfTwo : (float -> float)`

Maybe Im not getting the whole type signature deal. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: See also: http://lorgonblog.wordpress.com/2008/04/03/f-function-types-fun-with-tuples-and-currying/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to kongo2002:

The last item in the `->` chain is the `return type`, *not* another argument. The first accepts two floats and returns a float, and the second accepts one float and returns one.

The idea of doing it like that, and not something like `(float, float) : float`, is that you can use a concept called "currying". `generatePowerOfFunc` is of type `float -> float -> float`, which is equivalent to `float -> (float -> float)`, so we can give it a single float and get back a function of type `float -> float` (and we can give it another float, and get back a float).

This means that when you call `generatePowerOfFunc 2. 4.`, you apply *twice*. Once you apply `2.`, and once you apply `4.`.

Comment: forgot about the currying stuff. Now it makes a lot more sense. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The function `generatePowerOfFunc` takes two arguments of type `float` and returns a `float` value:

```
val generatePowerOfFunc : float -> float -> float
//                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                        arguments
//                                          ^^^^^
//                                          return value
```

The function `powerOfTwo` is like a partial function application that just takes one `float` argument (the exponent) and returns a `float`.

Comment: I know this is pretty old, but I still want to comment on the inaccuracy of your answer `generatePowerOfFunc` does not take two arguments. It takes one. It is likely that the OP was not familiar that FSI does not output the signature in a more readable manner. The signature is actually, `val generatePowerOfFunc : float -> (float -> float)`. It takes in a `float` as an arg and returns a function with the signature `float -> float`. This is based on what is written by the OP.